# c++ accessors mutators not reading cin switch case statement

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, accessor, mutators

I am using Ubuntu terminal g++ compiler for this , its hard for me to debug

Here is my code :
S.h

```
 class S
    {
    protected: 
        string name;
        bool space;
    public:
        S();
        S(string,bool);       
        void setName(string name);
    string getName();
};
```

In my S.cpp

```
string S::getName() 
{   
    return (name);  
}

void S::setName(string name) // I tried to change to other variable names but gave me segmentation errors
{
   name = name;
}

S::S() // default constructor
{
    name = "";
    space = true;
}

    S::S(string name, bool space) // non-default constructor
{
        name = name;
        space= space;
    }
```

I got another class which I am going to implement the flow
In my Main.cpp

```
    void Main::mainmenu()
{
    //cout displays//

    cout<<"Please input your choice: ";
    cin>>choice;
    option(choice);
}
    void Main::option(int choice)
{

    static string shapename;
    static bool space;
    const int size = 100;
    static S s[size];
    static int number =0;
    static int count = 0;

    while(choice !=999)
    { 

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: 
            {
                cout<<"Please enter name of Shape:";
                cin>>shapename;
                s[size].setName(shapename);
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                  count++;
                mainmenu();
                cin>>number;
                option(number);

            }
            break;
            case 2:
            {

                 for(int x = 0;x<count;x++)
                {   
                    cout<<count<<endl;
                    cout<<shapename<<endl; // this is to test if the string reaches case 2 and it displays the correct input
                    cout<<s[x].getName()<<endl; // however this method prints a blank.
                }

                mainmenu();
                cin>>number;
                option(number); 
            }
            break;
            default:break;
        } // end of switch      
    } // end of while  
}
```

I am just running `mainmenu()` in my `int main()`

I am trying to do a switch case on my main.cpp whereby the case 1 I get user to input the name they want and I use set method from class S to get the name , and in my case 2 , I want to retrieve and print out the name the user input by using get method .

I have put static infront of my delcarations because I thought the invocations might affect the values .

How can I retrieve my get/set methods with switch case statement ?  I am using Ubuntu terminal to do this its very difficult for me to see what values are being passed in.

Comment: you will get ah, uh, stack overflow after a number of run. think about the logic of code again

Answer (score 1):

```
 s[size].setName(shapename);
```

Always writes to the same spot, and it is outside the array. Pretty sure you want

```
 s[count].setName(shapename);
```

Once you have this bit of nasty fixed, you can deal with the name shadowing bug  in `setName` without triggering a segfault.

Off topic:

All those static variables should probably be class member variables.

Recursion is not a good choice inside the `while` loop. both try to accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this can help you a little bit.

Consider this:

```
void S::setName(string name)
{
   name = name;
}
```

What you are doing here is initialize the variable *name* with the value of *name*, aka you are setting *name* with it's own value.

This is known as *variable shadowing*.

To avoid it, is best practice to prefix you private data member, such as

```
class S
{
protected: 
    string _name;
    bool _space;
    ...
};
```

so, for example, your setter will be

```
void S::setName(string name) 
{
   _name = name;
}
```

another way is to explicitly access your members using *this* as following

```
void S::setName(string name) 
{
   this->name = name;
}
```

It is a matter of taste if you want to prefix your data members, use *this* or both.

Comment: Prefixes are a great idea, but before using an underscore [you should be aware of the rules.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Yes, I totally agree @user4581301

Comment: In the last example, you should show the definition of the private member name.